# how to iterate through xml child elements

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, gis

I have this xml tag code which looks as follows:

```
<FeatureLayerExtension>
    <WhereString>(ZONE ='A') or (ZONE ='V')</WhereString>
    <OutFields>ZONE</OutFields>
    <UniqueDataCount>2</UniqueDataCount>
    <UniqueValueRenderer>
        <SimpleFillSymbol  Color="White" Fill="Yellow" Width="1.5" Fvalue ='A'  />
        <SimpleFillSymbol  Color="White" Fill="Green" Width="1.5" Fvalue ='V' />
    </UniqueValueRenderer>
</FeatureLayerExtension>
```

I use this  in .Cs page  with help of serialization in the following way:

```
 if (projectMap.FeatureLayerConfig != null && projectMap.FeatureLayerConfig.UniqueValueRenderer != null)
        {
           agisFeatureLayer.RendererTakesPrecedence = true;                
            var renderer = new UniqueValueRenderer();
            renderer.Field = projectMap.FeatureLayerConfig.OutFields;


            for (int i = 0; i <= projectMap.FeatureLayerConfig.UniqueDataCount - 1; i++)
            {
                UniqueValueInfo info = new UniqueValueInfo();

                if (projectMap.FeatureLayerConfig.UniqueValueRenderer.SimpleFillSymbol != null)
                {
                    var fill = GlobalConfigs.ColorToStringDic[projectMap.FeatureLayerConfig.UniqueValueRenderer.SimpleFillSymbol.Fill];
                    var borderBrush = GlobalConfigs.ColorToStringDic[projectMap.FeatureLayerConfig.UniqueValueRenderer.SimpleFillSymbol.Color];
                    var borderThickness = projectMap.FeatureLayerConfig.UniqueValueRenderer.SimpleFillSymbol.Width;
                    var fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(fill), BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(borderBrush), BorderThickness = borderThickness };


                    info.Value = PojectMap.FeatureLayerConfig.UniqueValueRenderer.UniqueValueInfo.SimpleFillSymbol.Fvalue;
                    info.Symbol = fillSymbol;
                    renderer.Infos.Add(info);

                }

            }

            agisFeatureLayer.Renderer = renderer;
        }
    }
```

For the second child element SimpleFillSymbol of Fvalue 'V'  I unable to get it show during the rendering. The SimpleFillSymbol value 'A' renders twice as shown in the table of contents..How can i make the second fill symbol to show by iterating through the child elements

Code for the serilaization of the xml to object:

```
 using System.Xml.Serialization;
 using System.Windows.Media;

 namespace My.GIS.Viewer.Configuration.Map
  {
public partial class PortalFeatureLayer
{

    [XmlElement(typeof(uvRendererConfig), ElementName = "UniqueValueRenderer")]
    public uvRendererConfig UniqueValueRenderer { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(typeof(int), ElementName = "UniqueDataCount")]
    public int UniqueDataCount { get; set; }

}


public class uvRendererConfig
{

    [XmlElement(typeof(mySimpleFillSymbol), ElementName = "SimpleFillSymbol")]
    public mySimpleFillSymbol SimpleFillSymbol { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(typeof(mySimpleMarkerSymbol), ElementName = "SimpleMarkerSymbol")]
    public mySimpleMarkerSymbol SimpleMarkerSymbol { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(typeof(mySimpleLineSymbol), ElementName = "SimpleLineSymbol")]
    public mySimpleLineSymbol SimpleLineSymbol { get; set; }

}





public class mySimpleFillSymbol : SymbolBase {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Fill")]
    public string Fill { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "FieldValue")]
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }


}


public class SymbolBase
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Width")]
    public double Width { get; set; }       
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the classes for XML deserialization as follows:

```
namespace My.GIS.Viewer.Configuration.Map
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class FeatureLayerExtension
    {

        public string WhereString{ get; set; }

        public string OutFields { get; set; }

        public string UniqueDataCount { get; set; }

        //SimpleFillSymbol should be a list   
        [XmlElement("SimpleFillSymbol")]
        public List<SimpleFillSymbol> SimpleFillSymbolList = new List<SimpleFillSymbol>();

    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class SimpleFillSymbol
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Color")]
        public string Color { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Fill")]
        public string Fill { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Width")]
        public string Width { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Fvalue")]
        public string Fvalue { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Use the following code to fetch the list of SimpleFillSymbol objects

```
public class DeserializeFeatureLayerExtension
{

    public void desiralizeXML()
    {
        XmlSerializer fledeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FeatureLayerExtension));
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(file path);
        FeatureLayerExtension fleData = (FeatureLayerExtension)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    //Fetch the list of SimpleFillSymbol objects
    List<SimpleFillSymbol> listSimpleFillSymbol = (from e in fleData
                                                     select e.SimpleFillSymbolList);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using linq:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(document path);
var ell = from e in xelement.Descendants("SimpleFillSymbol")
          select e.Attribute("Fvalue");
```

Will return both the Fvalue attributes for the element SimpleFillSymbol

Comment: Than You for the response Nipun but I already have a separate file for serialization ..if you see the code for .cs file posted You will know. So i guess cannot use the XML to linq code here.. So basically I need some this like this  Foreach(var child in projectMap.FeatureLayerConfig.UniqueValueRenderer) {}..someting like this

Comment: So you mean to say that you have serialized the XML file into an object and in that case also you can use LINQ to Objects

Comment: HI Nipun..Thanks for keeping up with me.. I have edited my question where  I ahve posted my serialization code..Hope That gives you a better understanding of my question..I am still new to all the LINQ to objects concept..

Comment: Thats very easy you have to learn basics of LINQ. Using linq you can query any kind of data store. It will be good if you can learn LINQ which you can do here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx and Linq To Objects here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26743/Using-LINQ-to-Objects-in-C. I am going to add another answer for your question.

Comment: Thank you very much Nipun. Helped me a great deal.